# FatalErrorException in routes

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm a begginer in this PHP framework, Laravel .. so I got this problem , tryin' to fix it from hours and does't work.

**FatalErrorException in routes.php line 24:
syntax error, unexpected '}'**

i have maded all the steps until here , learning from this course of Mindspace on youtube , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJIc9lVTJj4&index=1&list=PL55RiY5tL51oloSGk5XdO2MGjPqc0BxGV#t=741.263237

(ps. i have maded also the connection with database and all these stuffs presented in that tutorial)

my routes.php

```
<?php
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP 
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() { 
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
        });
    Route::post('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
        'as' => 'signup'
    ])
}); ---- line 24 is here
```

and UserController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
    $email = $request['email'];
    $first_name = $request['first_name'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']); 
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->first_name = $first_name;
    $user->password = $password;

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

and the welcome.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first_name">Your First Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Your Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have show 11 lines of `Routes.php` and an error message about line number 30??? Not overly helpful. Show all of `Routes.php` or all we can do is make **guesses**

Comment: I have change it now . Sorry for this misunderstood .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a semicolon:

```
    // ...
    Route::post('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
        'as' => 'signup'
    ]); // <<=== HERE
});
```

Comment: oh my god ... thank you very much for your remark.
this semicolon takes me about 1,5 hours...